# Export Excel Range to Word

Tags: excel, vba

From Excel using VBA I want to copy a range from Excel to Word and I'm stuck!
I'm trying to recreate what I do manually by:

1. Select a Range of cells and COPY
2. Open a Word Doc
3. Select "Paste Special" and "Formatted Text (RTF)"

I've tried multiple versions of code that I've found on the internet but I am unable to get the code to run.  I do have the "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" Checked as a reference in Excel.

The Error I get is "Run Time Error 91 - Object Variable or With Block Variable not set". I have marked in the code below where it fails.  When I run this it launches Word but it does not open a new document.

Here's the code that has gotten me the farthest.

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
 
    Dim PageNumber As Integer
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim FileToOpen As String
    Dim strPath As String
 
    FileToOpen = "Excel Link test.docx"
    strPath = "C:\"
 
    'the next line looks to a cell to decide what page number to scroll to
    PageNumber = 1 'Later
 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(strPath & FileToOpen)
    Else
        On Error GoTo notOpen
        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents(FileToOpen)
        GoTo OpenAlready
notOpen:
        Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(strPath & FileToOpen)
    End If
 
OpenAlready:
 
    On Error GoTo 0
    Range("A6:D11").Copy ' med WS Name
    With wrdApp
 '------> Fails Here
        .Selection.Goto What:=1, Which:=2, Name:=PageNumber
        .Visible = True
        .Selection.Paste
    End With
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
 
End Sub
```

As always, thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, add `wrdApp.Visible = True` just before `With wrdApp` and place a breakpoint on this line (`With wrdApp`). In order to do that, click on this code line and press F9. Can you see a Word session with the document you wanted opening? Then press F5 (to run the rest of the code). Does it stop on the same code line?

Comment: If it still raise that error, please add this code line `If dir(strPath & FileToOpen) = "" Then MsgBox "FileToOpen does not exist..."` after `strPath = "C:\"`. Does it send a message?

Comment: Thank you and I think you are on to something.  I manually created the Word file and that stopped the Msgbox from displaying. The Word App opens to the "select your document" page, but the file does not open.  I'd like it to just open a "Blank Document".  The Code now stops at the new     wrdApp.Visible = True     statement that you suggested I add.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot get you... What do you mean by **"select your document" page**? Then, what does "The Code now stops at the new `wrdApp.Visible = True`" mean? Does it raise an error? If so, what error?

Comment: I will post an answer adapting the code in the area of setting the Word application, where `On Error Resume Next` masks some potential errors and you cannot know where they happens and creating a new "Blank Document", as you require.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It will open a new blank document and use it instead of the one being open by code:

```
Sub ExcelToWord() 
    Dim PageNumber As Integer, wrdApp As Word.Application, wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
    PageNumber = 1
 
    On Error Resume Next
     Set wrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
     If wrdApp Is Nothing Then
        err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add 'add a blank document
    wrdApp.Visible = True             'make Word application visible
                                      'only for debugging, if not want to be visible
                                      'and you will save it (programmatically) in the next steps...
    sh.Range("A6:D11").copy ' med WS Name
    With wrdApp
        .Selection.Goto What:=1, which:=2, Name:=PageNumber
        .Visible = True
        .Selection.Paste
    End With
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing: Set wrdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Again, thank you, but no go.... It stops on the "Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")" line. Oddly, if I run it with a breakpoint it gives me the error "Run-time error '7':Out of memory". but If I run it with no breakpoints it stops on the same line but the error is "Run-time error '-2146959355 (80080005)': Automation error". In either case, it opens the Word App to the page that lists all your recent documents and more. (Hope that's clearer).

Comment: @Flynt Moreland Did you run the above code **exactly as it is**? If not, please run it as it is and try modifying only after seeing it working. Any modification, even a small one,  can produce an error and I cannot imagine what modification has been done. The code is tested on my laptop and it works as it should.

Comment: I believe I did, but to make sure, I created a new Workbook with only 1 worksheet. Then I copied your code exactly. When I run it, stops on the "Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")" line. Each time I run it, it seems to alternate between the  "Run-time error '7':Out of memory". and the "Run-time error '-2146959355 (80080005)': Automation error". In either case, it opens the Word App to the page that lists all your recent documents and more just like before. Could this have anything to do with running Office on a Mac? Is there a way to share my spreadsheet?  Again, thank you!